# excel SolveOK options

Tags: excel, vba, optimization, solver

The SolverOK example below specifies the goal function through a cell (SetCell)

```
SolverOk SetCell:=Range("B8"), MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=10000
```

Is there an option to define the goal function by a VBA function? something like

```
SolverOk SetFun:="MyFunction", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=10000
```

Thank you

tried to do (wilde guess)

```
SolverOk SetCell:=("MyFunction"), MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=10000 and it did not work
```

Comment: You could assign the return value from `MyFunction` B8, depending on exactly what that function does....

Comment: Well, as I mentined I did that and it did not work.  I also mentioned that this was a wild guess. Is solver accepting this: SetCell:=("MyFunction") ?

Comment: I meant to try typing in B8 `=MyFunction()` and then run solver as in your first example.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work. When I tried to start the solver it did not repond.
I wonder if there is any documentation about this. I searched the internet and did not find anything

Comment: It should work as long as your function returns a value and the output depends on the cells being changed.  If you're still stumped it might help to provide the code for the function.